# How do I grant permissions with ADB, error

Tags: android, usb, adb

So I tried to run:
`./adb shell pm grant com.arlosoft.macrodroid android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`

But I keep getting error:
`Exception occurred while executing 'grant': java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.`

I run Android 13.

I tried looking for settings that may cause the problem, I turned 'Verify apps over USB' off, yet nothing helped. Also all of the past quesions seem to be old and outdated.